# Passing parameters through hyperlink

Tags: html, jsp, redirect, hyperlink

I have a web app that includes some hyperlinks in it that redirect the user to another page with some info as parameters. More specifically, my hyperlinks include sql queries as parameters.

I do this like so:

```
<a href="somepage.jsp?query=<%=stringSQLQuery%>"></a>
```

However, whenever my sql query included wildcards as a search term, like %, I get the following error message in my log files:

```
Character decoding failed. Parameter [string] with value ...
```

So pretty much, I don't think I can pass an SQL query through a hyperlink with wildcards in it. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: why do you need to pass a full sql query as a parameter? isnt the user supposed to provide only the params for the query? is that secure enough for your app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLs are restrictive in allowed characters. The `%` is a reserved character indicating the start of an URL-encoded character.

The request parameters must be [URL-encoded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding). The [JSTL](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info) `<c:url>` and `<c:param>` are designed for exactly this job.

```
<c:url var="somepage" value="somepage.jsp">
    <c:param name="query" value="${stringSQLQuery}" />
</c:url>
<a href="${somepage}">link</a>
```

As mentioned by everyone, you're however making a huge design mistake here with passing SQL strings around as request parameters. Rather work with fixed commands which are stored in some `Map` or maybe RESTful URLs.

Answer (score 1):

you need to [uri encode your parameters.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

I think this is what you want:

```
<a onclick='window.href.location = encodeURI("somepage.jsp?query=<%=stringSQLQuery%>");'>Click me</a>
```

See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7F6f5/)

Also, passing SQL's through like that is a ***bad bad bad idea***. Anybody has access to your DB.

Comment: OP is using JSP, not JavaScript.

Comment: a great feature of JSP pages is you can use javascript too :P

Comment: I understand it's a terrible, terrible idea, but this is what my professor wants. :/

Answer (score 0):

you can pass pamameters or values using hyperlink

as Example: 
   i have one page display.html and pass the parameter a and b and there values 10 and 20 respectively. in anchor tag we will href as below.

```
                      href="xyz.html?a=10&b=20"
```